# Graphql dependency convergency issue

Tags: spring, graphql

I keep getting dependency converge issue with graphql. How can I resolve this?

Dependency convergence error for `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.3-2` paths to dependency are:

```
  +-com.graphql-java:graphql-java-tools:3.2.0
    +-org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.3-2
and

  +-com.graphql-java:graphql-java-tools:3.2.0
    +-com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.8.8
      +-org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.1.1
        +-org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.1
```

My graph ql dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
    <artifactId>graphql-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
    <artifactId>graphql-java-tools</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
</dependency>
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `graphql-java` and `graphql-java-tools` you are using are very old version. Also , `graphql-java-tools` is migrated to another `groupId` which is called `com.graphql-java-kickstart`. They are actually [developed and maintained by different teams](https://www.graphql-java.com/blog/moving-projects/) which `graphql-java-tools` is built on top of `graphql-java`.

I highly recommend you update them to the latest version which fix a lot of bugs and also have many useful features.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
    <artifactId>graphql-java</artifactId>
    <version>13.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
    <artifactId>graphql-java-tools</artifactId>
    <version>5.7.1</version>
</dependency>
```